# Python Requests - POST confusion

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I've been banging my head against the wall...can anyone help me wrap my brain around getting a post request to work?

I'm trying to do work on a website but first I have to get past the login... I've been googling, but so far I can't get it sorted out. I'm super n00b to web stuff but have some experience in python in Maya.

Here is what I have so far

```
import requests
login_url = 'https://example.com/examplelogin
login_payload = {'j_username':'myusername', 'j_password':'mypassword'}
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(login_url, data = login_payload)
```

Here is the form I'm trying to fill:

```
<form id="login" action="/idp/Authn/UserPassword" method="post">
<p class="customError"></p>
<section>
<input id="username" class="form-element form-field" name="j_username" type="text" value="" placeholder="email address"></section>
<section>
<input id="password" class="form-element form-field" name="j_password" type="password" value="" placeholder="password"></section>
<button class="form-element form-button" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

for `r.status_code` I get `200` but `r.text` is just the login page HTML... It doesn't log me in and bring me through...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site does not have an API of some kind it is possible that you won't be able to use the requests lib to access it. You should look at [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) it will allow you to use FireFox to access the page. If you want a headless version which is often much faster you can use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver


driver = WebDriver()
driver.get('https://example.com/examplelogin')

username = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('password')

username.send_keys('MY_USERNAME')
password.send_keys('MY_PASSWORD')

submit.click()
```

Comment: The site doesn't have an API that is available to the user (instructors at the institution). I have a Selenium version of the script running but when it comes time to do the work (posting grades and comments from an excel to the site) it is extremely slow (2-3min for 25 grades).  I am hoping to find a faster solution to this and it was suggested to me to access the forms directly. Maybe there are other solutions of which I am not aware...?

Comment: You should take a look at http://phantomjs.org/ it will speed up the process and you won't need to rebuild your scripts. It's also possible that it won't be possible to do it with requests. I ran into the same issue a couple months ago when trying to automate some tasks at work.

Comment: Initial testing using phantomjs seems to be promising. I won't be able to do a 'real' test until next week...but so far it does run faster. It did introduce a couple of bugs that required a `time.sleep()` in order to get everything working...but I'm happy enough with it and I'm moving on. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Requests is a HTTP library. You have to read about [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), for what is before use it.

> HTTP functions as a request-response protocol in the client-server computing model. A web browser, for example, may be the client and an application running on a computer hosting a web site may be the server. The client submits an HTTP request message to the server. The server, which provides resources such as HTML files and other content, or performs other functions on behalf of the client, returns a response message to the client. The response contains completion status information about the request and may also contain requested content in its message body.

In fact your form should do the same as POST request. You have to read about [forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) also.

I think it will be a good idea to complete a tutorial to understand how it works. [There is a good place to start.](https://www.codecademy.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will give those a read... My HTTP knowledge is definitely lacking a bit.

Comment: The forms link was particularly enlightening. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You want to send request to **/idp/Authn/UserPassword** instead of **/examplelogin**. If form has action attribute, browser will send POST to the specified address in that attribute.

But still, if you want to work with site, it's better to use Selenium as @emett-speer suggested because you probably don't want to talk with site manually (what if URL will be changed etc.).

Comment: When I attempt to post to **/idp/Authn/UserPassword** I get a `404 Not Found` status in return.  I'm running a few more tests but will probably move to testing phantomjs to speed up my Selenium implementation instead of dragging on with `requests` getting now where... Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: You can look how browser creates request when it sends forms data. Just press F12 on target page, move to Network tab and press "Log in" on the form (make sure that you enabled persistent logging if browser cleans requests list in tab).